# How to pass data between view controllers - not working

Tags: swift, uikit, uilabel, interface-builder, uistoryboardsegue

Im trying to pass an player score from VC1 to a view that displays the current scores of all players(4).  the display view is on a separate view controller than where the player(s) score is defined and stored.

I have done the prepare(segue) and im able to pass other variables to the display VC(ThirdViewController). but when I try to assign the player score to the uilabel.text It tells me that I have unwrapped a nil value

I have even tried to just set the label text to a static string and still get the nil error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var name = String()

var player1Score = 1
var player2Score = 2
var player3Score = 3
var player4Score = 4

//MARK: ********* IBOutlets **********
@IBOutlet weak var playerSegmentOutlet: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var diceSegmentOutlet: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var targetScoreSliderOutlet: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var matchTargetSwitchOutlet: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var targetScoreLabel: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let VC = segue.destination as? SecondViewController {

        VC.player1CurrentScore = player1Score
        VC.player2CurrentScore = player2Score
        VC.player3CurrentScore = player3Score
        VC.player4CurrentScore = player4Score
    }
}
```

Second view Controller

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentRoundScoreLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var CurrentPlayerScoreLabel: UILabel!

var player1CurrentScore = 1
var player2CurrentScore = 1
var player3CurrentScore = 1
var player4CurrentScore = 1


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let VC = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {

        VC.player1ScoreLabel.text = String(player1CurrentScore)
        VC.player2ScoreLabel.text = String(player2CurrentScore)
        VC.player3ScoreLabel.text = String(player3CurrentScore)
        VC.player4ScoreLabel.text = String(player4CurrentScore)

    }
}
```

Third View Controller

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var player1ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var player2ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var player3ScoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var player4ScoreLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

no matter what I try to do with with UILabel.text it shows up as nil

I'm totally frustrated and I'm sure I am missing something simple because of my frustration, please someone help me.

Comment: You should never assign the content of the destVC IBOutlet from prepare: that does not work because the IBOutlet does not exist yet. You need to set some destVC properties (declared usually as optional in destVC) ; then, in viewDidLoad of destVC, use these properties to set the IBOutlets (labels or others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an inefficient way to do this as you are passing data through 3 different objects. However, going on with this methodology, the problem is the label's are not created yet inside

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let VC = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {

        VC.player1ScoreLabel.text = String(player1CurrentScore)
        VC.player2ScoreLabel.text = String(player2CurrentScore)
        VC.player3ScoreLabel.text = String(player3CurrentScore)
        VC.player4ScoreLabel.text = String(player4CurrentScore)

    }
}
```

See, the label isn't created yet. So, you are setting `text` on a`UILabel` that isn't initialized. Therefore, you need to create variables for the labels inside `ThirdViewController`.

Third View Controller

```
class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var player1ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var player2ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var player3ScoreLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var player4ScoreLabel: UILabel!

    var score0:Int!
    var score1:Int!
    var score2:Int!
    var score3:Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.player1ScoreLabel.text = String(score0)
        self.player2ScoreLabel.text = String(score1)
        self.player3ScoreLabel.text = String(score2)
        self.player4ScoreLabel.text = String(score3)
    }
}
```

and change the segue in SecondViewController

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let VC = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {

        VC.score0 = player1CurrentScore
        VC.score1 = player2CurrentScore
        VC.score2 = player3CurrentScore
        VC.score3 = player4CurrentScore

    }
}
```

---

**Another Way:**

Let's create a singleton called `Game`. Within this (assuming you only have 4 players) we can create 4 players that will **never change**. This allows us to create instances of players in one location and call upon them as necessary.

**NOTE:** A singleton can be misused EASILY.

https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-singleton-and-how-to-create-one-in-swift
https://cocoacasts.com/are-singletons-bad/

```
class Game {

    static var score0:Int = 0
    static var score1:Int = 0
    static var score2:Int = 0
    static var score2:Int = 0

}
```

Then, anywhere in your code you can access Game.score0, Game.score1.

**CAUTION:**

I would caution you to very carefully use singletons. You don't want everything with public access. You need to determine if this is good for you or not. Cheers.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a ton I was about to pull my hair out :), and I don't have any to spare.

Comment: you mentioned that was inefficient, how would you implement it.

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Give me some time, so you can keep working with this :P

Comment: There ya go! Somewhat efficient :P